# Crossposting to other Stack Exchange sites if question is unanswered on Ask Ubuntu

Tags: discussion, best-practice

I am relatively new to Ask Ubuntu and stack exchange in general, but I read that x-posting is relatively frowned upon here. Is it acceptable to post a question to another Stack Exchange site, say, Superuser, if the question is not answered here in Ask Ubuntu? What's the best practice for doing so? Should one delete the old question so that it does not show up twice on a search engine?

Comment: Reposting the same thing somewhere else is just throwing another dart, you can keep improving your question over time to get it a better chance to be answered, I've retitled it so it's easier to read from the front page and I'll ping the lightdm maintainer.

Comment: (Also ask your grep question as a new question please!)

Comment: thanks for the remarks about my question! Although it really was not specifically for that one but just generally about the x-posting customs here. You dont have to answer it now just because this question here!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Cross-posting the same question across StackExchange sites, within a few minutes, definitely seems spammish, to me. If, however, your question hasn't got attention and you can't add more details or raise a bounty for it in Ask Ubuntu, I don't see a problem with it if you can get attention on a more appropriate site.

<strike>Personally, I would delete my question here if you were able to get responses elsewhere.</strike>

Disregard the previous sentence. In hindsight, it was unnecessary. If you are a regular contributor, here, by all means, I would recommend coming back and answering your own question to add to the AU knowledge-base.

I think that there are good cases to be made for self-deleting one's questions. But, that is probably good for another topic.

We are all volunteers here, so it just may take a while for a question to catch our attention.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Is putting a x-post tag in the title necessary or rather annoying?

Comment: @YumTum I don't think that there is any need to indicate in the title that you are looking elsewhere for solutions.